# Javascript Logical Operator not validating

Tags: javascript

A simple javascript logical operator validation is not working for me.

eg. Target Price should not be greater than orginal price

```
x = input from user;
y = 1000; // fixed

if(x > 1000 )
{
  alert ( x+'should not be greater than'+y);
}
else
{
  alert ( ' proceed' );
}
```

here is my [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5t422enw/)

Comment: Your example works fine in Chrome

Comment: use  if (parseInt(targetPrice) > parseInt(orginalPrice))

Answer (score 0):

Those values are of type `string`, you need to convert them to `number`. You can use `Number()` for that.

```
    targetPrice = Number($('#pdiwap_dropamt').val());
    orginalPrice = Number($('#orgprice_wap').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Because both the operands string so it does a string comparison.

You can convert the values to a number and then do the comparison like

```
    targetPrice = +$('#pdiwap_dropamt').val();
    orginalPrice = +$('#orgprice_wap').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are compering two strings. Use something like this

```
 if (parseInt(targetPrice) > parseInt(orginalPrice))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `parseInt` function to validate correctly. Bucause html input gives the value in string format.

```
if (parseInt(targetPrice,10) > parseInt(orginalPrice,10))
```

[Updated Link](https://jsfiddle.net/5t422enw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is from the input you're getting which is seen as a string. Try converting to integer first before comparing.

e.g x = parseInt(Input from user);

Answer (score 0):

Yes! it input value is a string so its not validate properly.

Try This.

```
var x  = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var y  = 1000;
    if(!isNaN(x) && x < 1000) {
      alert ('proceed' );
    } else {
      alert(x+'should not be greater than'+y);
    }
```